# Code for sharing buttons to facebook, twitter and buzz with counter

Tags: facebook, twitter, share, buzz

I am looking for the code to implement share buttons for twitter, buzz and facebook with a counter like youtube have in their share option, please see the screen shot.

[image]

I’ve been looking over some codes but none of them does exactly what I want, either it is a bit square or it is a “like count” to facebook.

I hope one of you could help me with this.

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Facebook, look here: [Facebook for Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

For Twitter API, look here: [Twitter for developers](http://dev.twitter.com/)

And, for Google Buzz: [Buzz counter](http://www.google.com/buzz/stuff?hl=en)

Comment: Hi Ardman, thanks for the links - they are really useful but I have one question thou. The facebook link, the only buttons I can find is the "like" button with a counter and not a "share" button, which is what I'm really looking for. Do you know anything about that? Otherwise thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mestika: The `Like` button is a better option compared to the `Share` button.  For example, if the person `Like`'s your site, it is prepopulated with your `Open Graph` meta tags and your site then has a `Connection`.  This will then appear on the top 5% of your new `Connection`'s friends `News Feeds`.  People who visit a site and see their friends faces are more inclined to engage with the content.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

AddThis ([www.addthis.com](http://www.addthis.com/)) provide a variety of configuration options and icons with an easy to use JavaScript snippet and clickthrough stats.